# C# virtual keyword

Tags: c#

Is a virtual method compulsory to override by its subclass?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If a method is not virtual (or abstract), it can't be overriden in the sub class. The only option then is to use the `new` keyword to hide the inherited method, but this is generally not a recommended practice, since casting the instance of the sub class to the parent class and calling the method will cause the parent class method to be called instead, and that is probably not the intended functionality.

So in short, yes it needs to be virtual to override, but no you dont *have* to override it. If you don't, the base class version will be called instead. But if you do override it, even if you cast the object to it base class type, the derived version of the method will be called, unlike for hiding the method with new.

It's good to know the difference between overriding and hiding the method, since at first glance, and if you test it, it might look like it does the same thing, but will come back to bite you later when the program don't work as expected, and you have no idea why.

Comment: sir can u please elaborate on this also overrinding vs hiding the method

Comment: is it also necessary to put virtual key word before overriding it, without this it doesn't work?

Comment: Which aspect did you want to get elaborated. The difference between virtual/override and new?

Comment: Yes, that is my point exactly. If you don't mark it as virtual in the bas class, you can't mark it as override in the derived class, and if you want to use the same method name in that case, that means the derived class will have to qualify the method with new, but that will probably not behave as you expect it to without knowing all the details regarding qualifying the method with new, and thereby hiding the base implementation of the method.

Comment: The difference (among others) is that is you have class A that is a base class and B that is a derived class, and both have a method called Test. It's not virtual in A but it written like public new void Test in B. Then you make a object of B, and write B.Test. The derived class Test is run as you would expect. If you instead make a object of B and cast it to A (allowed since B derive of A) and call the casted B's Test method, actually the base class implementation of Test is called and that is usually not what you want. If you use virtual/override, then the derived Test is run in both cases.

Comment: I think you said "overload" when you meant "override" a couple times there.

Comment: @Eric Lippert - As expected, you are 100% correct. I have fixed my inaccuracies now. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

No, when you are using "virtual" keyword, it's up to you whether you want to override or not. When you use "abstract", you need to override the method in the derived class. For more information, please see:

- *[virtual (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4%28VS.80%29.aspx)* (the keyword)
- *[abstract (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5%28VS.71%29.aspx)* (the modifier)

Comment: You are only *required* to override the abstract method in a derived class if the derived class is a *not abstract* class derived from an absract base class.

Answer (score 11):

No. It *can* be overriden by a sub class, but does not *have* to be.

If you want to enforce overriding by subclasses, use `abstract` in an `abstract` class, or use an interface (meaning you *have* to implement all declared members).

Comment: Note that to mark the method as abstract, you have to mark the class as abstract also, so if you want to create obejcts of the main class as well as the derived classes, you can't enforce the subclasses to override the method. An interface it another way to make sure that a class implements a specific set of methods.

Answer (score 10):

> Is a virtual method is compulsory to override by it's sub class?

No.

> Can I Override a method which is NON-Virtual in parent class ?

No.

> What is YES then ?

You must implement Abstract method of parent class (if derived class is non-abstract)

> Can I write Virtual keyword on Static method

**NO**, Because these two are just opposite words. Virtual means compiler does not know at compile time which method to be called. Static means , for sure , your compiler knows which method will be called.

> How do I stop my current class' subclasses to no Override my method ?

Mark it with sealed keyword.

> Is Abstract method a virtual also ?

YES. That's why we cant explicitly mark abstract method virtual as well.

> Is Override and Overload same ?

Off-course not!  Overloading is having 2 methods with same name but which works on different set of input parameters.

> When shall I Mark a method as Virtual ?

When you are using polymorphism and you are not sure about the type of the object passes to your method until runtime, and you want your subclasses to have different behavior then mark the method as Virtual.
e.g. You have

```
class Law
{
 public void Punish(Minister any)
 {
    if (any.Corruption() == true)
      {
        ... do whatever public wants...
      }
 }
}
```

And  you have Hierarchy of Minister classes -Ministers,  CentralGOVTMinisters , StateGOVTMinisters , DistrictAuthorityMinisters etc.  And you know that Whatever defined in Minister class for Corruption() method can be used by many derived class but for few ministers Corruption laws are different (they have supreme powers may be !) , so there  you override the Corruption() and everywhere else your derived classes use the implementation of Corruption() in Minister class (base of all minister).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, if a method is not marked virtual or abstract it cannot be overridden. The only exception is when declaring an interface method you don't need to use it because an interface method is virtual by definition. When you implement this interface you need to use virtual or abstract if you want to be able to derive from the class implementing the interface and be able to override the method.

Answer (score 3):

It is not compulsory to override virtual methods that are not abstract.

It is compulsory to implement abstract methods unless you also mark your class abstract.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not mandatory to override a virtual method in a derived class.

Answer (score 2):

yes to override you need to write virtual keyword. or write keyword abstract method.

Answer (score 2):

No, it just means that you can override it, not that you have to. Abstract is the keyword if you want to make it mandatory for the subclass to implement it.