# How can I return a Test Double without changing a method signature?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

If I have a class

```
public class OriginalThing
{
    public void DoesThing(List<string> stuff)
    {
        var s = "Original Thing";
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        stuff.Add(s);
    }
}
```

I can test it by saying:

```
    [Test]
    public void OriginalThing_DoesThing()
    {
        var strings= new List<string>();
        new OriginalThing().DoesThing(strings);
        strings.Should().NotBeEmpty();
        strings.Should().HaveCount(1);
        strings.ElementAt(0).Should().Contain("Original");
    }
```

I can also use Moq to have that object provided to me:

```
public interface IThingServer
{
    OriginalThing GetThing();
}

    [Test]
    public void ProvidedOriginalThing_DoesThing()
    {
        var strings= new List<string>();
        var thingServer = new Mock<IThingServer>();
        thingServer.Setup(ts => ts.GetThing()).Returns(new OriginalThing());
        thingServer.Object.GetThing().DoesThing(strings);

        strings.Should().NotBeEmpty();
        strings.Should().HaveCount(1);
        strings.ElementAt(0).Should().Contain("Original");
    }
```

Now, OriginalThing does not inherit from an interface nor is its method virtual so I cannot mock it in order to verify an interaction against it.

If I inherit from OriginalThing:

```
class FakeThing : OriginalThing
{
    public void DoesThing(List<string> stuff)
    {
        var s = "Fake Thing";
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        stuff.Add(s);
    }
}
```

Then I can use that in a test without calling the original method:

```
    [Test]
    public void FakeThing_DoesThing()
    {
        var strings = new List<string>();

        new FakeThing().DoesThing(strings);

        strings.Should().NotBeEmpty();
        strings.Should().HaveCount(1);
        strings.ElementAt(0).Should().Contain("Fake");
    }
```

If I try to have Moq provide that FakeThing or make my own manual Factory using a new interface

```
public interface IThingFactory
{
    OriginalThing GetThing();
}

public class FakeThingFactory : IThingFactory
{
    public OriginalThing GetThing()
    {
        return new FakeThing();
    }
}

public class OriginalThingFactory : IThingFactory
{
    public OriginalThing GetThing()
    {
        return new OriginalThing();
    }
}
```

If I now add two more tests

```
    [Test]
    public void ProvidedOriginalThing_DoesThing()
    {
        var strings = new List<string>();
        var factory = new OriginalThingFactory();
        var originalThing = factory.GetThing();

        originalThing.Should().BeOfType<OriginalThing>();

        originalThing.DoesThing(strings);
        strings.Should().NotBeEmpty();
        strings.Should().HaveCount(1);
        strings.ElementAt(0).Should().Contain("Original");
    }

    [Test]
    public void ProvidedFakeThing_DoesThing()
    {
        var strings = new List<string>();
        var factory = new FakeThingFactory();
        var fakeThing = factory.GetThing();

        fakeThing.Should().BeOfType<FakeThing>();

        fakeThing.DoesThing(strings);

        strings.Should().NotBeEmpty();
        strings.Should().HaveCount(1);
        strings.ElementAt(0).Should().Contain("Fake");
    }
```

Then the ProvidedFakeThing_DoesThing method fails on the `strings.ElementAt(0).Should().Contain("Fake");` line. This is because even though it passes the test that it is an instance of `FakeThing` it actually calls the base `OriginalThing.DoesThing` method.

I can cast `fakeThing as FakeThing` and the test will pass but... well, in the real world we have a method with three responsibilities each of which is to call out to a collaborator. We'd like to test that those three calls are made and this issue is what is blocking us.

Imagine a ThingHandler that has a ThingFactory, gets a Thing, and then calls DoesThing we'd like to be in control of the Thing without changing the code (and maybe that is equivalent to the moon on a stick)

We may be trying to do something silly or bad, but if there's a way to achieve this that we can't see that would be awesome.

A running example can be found at https://github.com/pauldambra/methodHiding/

Thanks in advance for reading so much!

Comment: Not sure if this helps too much, but why not use Moq to create a mock object of `Thing` and use that in your last test instead of a formal `FakeThing` class? Something like `Mock<Thing> fakeThing = new Mock<Thing>();`. Then you can mock each method of `Thing` that you need to. You can even use `fakeThing.CallBase = true;` to call base class methods if you choose.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker: I don't think you can mock concrete types unless their methods are virtual.

Comment: Yep, OriginalThing's methods aren't virtual so we can't override them. And don't want to change the object *just to make it testable* which might be unreasonable on our part!

Comment: @PaulD'Ambra: I don't think the feeling that you don't want to change classes just to make them testable is unreasonable.

Comment: Ah http://stackoverflow.com/a/3838070/222163 without virtual on the SubClass then casting as Parent Class causes parent class method to be called which is what we're seeing when returning from the factory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend reading [Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503627); it turns out that this is a problem that a lot of us run into. **Your test is trying to tell you something, as a consumer of your code.**

Ultimately, you are hoping to use [behavior verification](http://xunitpatterns.com/Behavior%20Verification.html) to ensure that the SUT is making the proper call to the `OriginalThing` dependency. However, you mention that creating a test double for `OriginalThing` is not straightforward, as it does not implement an interface.

So your test is telling you one of two things:

1. Things would be easier if `OriginalThing` implemented an interface; **or**
2. Things would be easier if you didn't test the SUT's dependency on `OriginalThing`

Your SUT obviously has a dependency on `OriginalThing`. Can this dependency be described with a [Role Interface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/RoleInterface.html)? Does the SUT really just need some external object that is capable of performing `DoesThing`? If so, then you've identified a [seam in your code](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=359417&seqNum=2).

What if `OriginalThing` is the only implementation that you would have for such a role? Isn't it overkill to define an interface for something that will only have a single implementation? Well, you've already identified another possible implementation - a test double.

(A test is just one consumer of your code. As such, if the test deems it useful to have the ability to specify a particular implementation for a role, this sentiment is likely be shared with other consumers.)

Now, if the SUT is truly dependent on `OriginalThing` (and not just any old object that can `DoesThing`) then you *shouldn't* be allowed to replace it with a test double. In that scenario, instead of verifying that `OriginalThing` is invoked, the test should verify that the SUT correctly handles the list populated by `OriginalThing`.

Modifying your code just to make it testable *is not a bad thing*. In fact, that's the impetus behind Test-Driven Development.